# create 3 selectbox(months, days, years) php looping options for each and Javascript to change options for `days` when `months` changes

Tags: javascript, php, loops, date, drop-down-menu

I have these select boxes as follow:

```
<?php 
echo'
<select id="months"></select>

<select id="days"></select>

<select id="years"></select>
'; ?>
```

I want the options for each select boxes to be the current date to be automatically selected on load. Like for example today(January 28, 2016): the first select box should have January selected. and the next one should be 18, and the last 1 should be 2016.

Actually I already got that working for the `days` select box with this code.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 31; $x++) {
        echo '<option value="'.$x.'" ';

        if ($x == date_format($nowdate,'d'))
        {
            echo 'selected';
        }
        echo' >'.$x.'</option>';
        }
```

But I don't know how to do it on `months`. And 1 more problem, I want when `months` changes, the `days` should also change its options depending on the number of days the selected month has. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Consider 2000-3000 as options included for `years` Select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code for populating months :

```
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
        $mon = date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$x));
        echo '<option value="'.$mon.'" ';
        if ($mon == date('F'))
        {
           echo 'selected';
        }
        echo' >'.$mon.'</option>';
    }
```

Same way, you can use date('Y') to figure out the current year.

Comment: thanks a lot. this helped! :)
but still one more problem. the javascript part. that when month changes the num of days should be as how many days the selected month has.

Answer (score 0):

For the JavaScript part, you can use the following code -

Onchange of months select box call the following function and pass two parameters (current selected month and selected year) -

```
    function getCurrentdays(month,year) {
        var currentdays = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();   
        populatedayscombo(currentdays);
    }

    function populatedayscombo(currentdays)
    {
        document.getElementById("monthscombo").options.length = 0;
        for (x = 1; x <= currentdays; x++) 
        {
            var newOption = document.createElement("option");
            newOption.text = x;
            newOption.value = x;
            document.getElementById("monthscombo").add(newOption);
        }
    }
```